# Java error: symbol not found

Tags: java

ok so i have this program that I copied from my tutor

```
import acm.program.*;
public class GRectPlusGOval extends GraphicsProgram {
   public void run() {
      GRect rect = new GRect(100, 50, 125, 60);
      rect.setFilled(true);
      rect.setColor(Color.RED);
      add(rect);
      GOval oval = new GOval(100, 50, 125, 60);
      oval.setFilled(true);
      oval.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
      add(oval);
   }
}
```

and when trying to compile it I get this message:

```
grectplusgoval.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
GRect rect = new GRect(100,50,125,60);
^
symbol:class GRect
location:class GRectPlusGOval

grectplusgoval.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
GRect rect = new GRect(100,50,125,60);
                 ^
symbol:class GRect
location:class GRectPlusGOval

grectplusgoval.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
rect.setColor(Color.RED);
               ^
symbol:variable Color
location:class GRectPlusGOval

grectplusgoval.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
GOval oval = new GOval(100,50,125,60)
^                
symbol:class GOval
location:class GRectPlusGOval

grectplusgoval.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
GOval oval = new GOval(100,50,125,60)
                 ^
symbol:class GOval
location:class GRectPlusGOval

grectplusgoval.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
oval.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
                  ^
symbol: variable Color
location:class GRectPlusGOval
6 errors
```

what is wrong and how can I correct this?

Comment: what is class `GRect `

Comment: Have you imported those classes?

Comment: It looks like you need to import `acm.graphics.*`.

Comment: This is it , when i imported acm.graphics.* and java.awt.* i managed to compile it. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find `ac.graphics.*` package. This package is missing in your project.